# How do I load datetime using pylab.loadtxt for readable x axis?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

I'm learning programming and am struggling with plotting date and time stamped date.  Basically I want to plot each of the columns either on the same graph or different graphs which I then save to png.

I have data in a tab delimitated file like below, where column 0 is is generated using a datetime.now()

```
2016-04-04 14:12:01.373941      9.814453        73.000000       283.886719      29.141235       24.312744       28.465576
2016-04-04 14:13:01.444061      9.738770        73.000000       272.570801      29.141235       24.312744       28.427124
2016-04-04 14:14:01.500493      9.404297        73.000000       268.395996      29.141235       24.312744       28.394165
2016-04-04 14:15:01.557931      10.075684       73.000000       295.532227      29.141235       24.312744       28.482056
2016-04-04 14:16:01.623930      9.528809        73.000000       258.947754      29.141235       24.312744       28.405151
2016-04-04 14:17:01.704351      9.343262        73.000000       277.844238      29.141235       24.312744       28.421631
2016-04-04 14:18:01.800740      9.714355        73.000000       254.113770      29.141235       24.312744       28.427124
```

If I use unix time with time.time() instead of datetime.now() it's a float which numpy interprets, but the x axis is not human readable.  Using the above data with this, it fails with an error below.  This is the code I was trying.

```
import pylab
import time
import os
os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0.0"

plotdailylogfilename = '/home/pi/Desktop/powersystem-logfiles/plotdailylog' + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + '.log'
data = pylab.loadtxt(plotdailylogfilename)
pylab.plot( data[:,0], data[:,1])
pylab.legend()
pylab.legend()
pylab.title("Charge Data for " + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
pylab.xlabel("Time")
pylab.ylabel("Solar datapoints")
pylab.savefig("/var/www/html/daily.png")
```

This is the error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-eb2bf978585e> in <module>()
----> 1 data = pylab.loadtxt(plotdailylogfilename)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin)
    846                 vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols]
    847             # Convert each value according to its column and store
--> 848             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
    849             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting
    850             items = pack_items(items, packing)

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2016-04-04
```

Which I interpret numpy as not parsing the date time stamp.  I'm confused as to how to get loadtxt to parse date time in a way that labels x axis in a readable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I specify `dtype=None`, then `np.genfromtxt` (a slightly more sophisticated version of `loadtxt`), produces:

```
In [110]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=None,delimiter=',')
In [111]: data
Out[111]: 
array([ (b'2016-04-04 14:12:01.373941', 9.814453, 73.0, 283.886719, 29.141235, 24.312744, 28.465576),
       (b'2016-04-04 14:13:01.444061', 9.73877, 73.0, 272.570801, 29.141235, 24.312744, 28.427124),
       (b'2016-04-04 14:14:01.500493', 9.404297, 73.0, 268.395996, 29.141235, 24.312744, 28.394165)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S26'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8')])
```

The floats are loaded just fine, and the dates are loaded as strings.  (I replaced your tabs with ',' for cut-n-paste purposes.  The 'b' is just Python3 bytestring designation.).

Note that the result is a 1d array with 7 `fields`.  I.e. a compound `dtype`.  Columns are accessed by name, `data['f0']`, `data['f2']`.

If I specify that the first field is a version of `datetime` I get:

```
In [112]: dt=np.dtype([('f0','datetime64[ms]'),('f1',float,(6))])

In [113]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=dt,delimiter=',')
In [114]: data
Out[114]: 
array([ (datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 4, 21, 12, 1, 373000), [9.814453, 73.0, 283.886719, 29.141235, 24.312744, 28.465576]),
       (datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 4, 21, 13, 1, 444000), [9.73877, 73.0, 272.570801, 29.141235, 24.312744, 28.427124]),
       (datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 4, 21, 14, 1, 500000), [9.404297, 73.0, 268.395996, 29.141235, 24.312744, 28.394165])], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<M8[ms]'), ('f1', '<f8', (6,))])
In [115]: data['f0']
Out[115]: 
array(['2016-04-04T14:12:01.373-0700', '2016-04-04T14:13:01.444-0700',
       '2016-04-04T14:14:01.500-0700'], dtype='datetime64[ms]')
```

Here I grouped the numeric fields into one with 6 columns, so `data['f1']` is a (3,6) array.

You can refine the datetime units.  `np.datetime64` is a form of the Python `datetime` that is stored as a 64 bit number.  I haven't used it in plotting, but `pylab` should be comfortable with it.